# AI conflict in Gargantia on the Verdurous Planet

Tags: suisei-no-gargantia

In Gargantia on the Verdurous Planet, I feel like the final conflict is trying to say something about AI in some way. But it feels very out of place from the AI depicted in episodes prior to the end few.

So is there more background, or is this explored more in another medium other than the half season anime series?

To dig a little deeper, Chamber seems no different than his pilot in his ability to assimilate into jobs on Gargantia. Where as Striker seems to have taken on a completely different persona. Unguided it doesn't seem like Chamber would end up the same place. I just feel like there is more to explored here that the authors would intend and I'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you say, the AI follows whats best from machine's point of view. Chamber even recommends multiple times that taking over Gargantia and becoming a leader is best way to achieve his goals of survival and getting back to Alliance. But Ledo stops him. This is reason why there is still pilot. Leaving critical decisions on a machine can result in really bad situations.

There is also OVA that explains how things happened on Kugel's side. Simply said, Kugel starts in similar position as Ledo, yet circumstances and misunderstanding lead him to what we saw in anime. Striker just continues what Kugel started.

As for Chamber vs. Striker at the end, it is easily explained by AIs being able to learn. Chamber learned, that while Gargantia does things inefficiently from Aliance's standard, it leads to much higher satisfaction and lives of people, along with Ledo's happiness. What is what Chamber looks out for most. Striker on the other side got confirmed it's way of thinking, so it tries to defend that.